# Constraint input length python sys.stdin.readline()

Tags: python, stdin

I try to solve algorithm problems from [this website](http://codeforces.com/)! The thing is that all the problem has to be implemented by system input.

So I would use

```py
from stdin import sys
a = stdin.readline()
# do something
```

My question is sometimes I need to do this like below.
The first line is the integer `n`(1n length of string or number which have `n` digits.

Let me give you an example.

#### input

```
4
1100
```

The thing is how to *constraint the second line matching 4 digits(length)* as input. How? and Why?

Comment: Best and easiest would be let the user input whatever and then check the value and in case it doesn't match print error and ask the user to try again.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you! Solved it by you and below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot constraint input length this way.

As @Andrey suggested, you should read the input, and if incorrect, print an error and read a new input.

By the way the pythonic way of [reading input in python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is:

```py
a = input("prompt")
```

So you can do something like:

```py
a = ""
while len(a) != 4:
    a = input("please enter a 4 digit number: ")
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!